# jquery eq selector loop for tumblr

Tags: jquery

I have a question that I've been stuck with for awhile: 
I'm using tumblr and trying to flip the img and the text of a "text post". So currently I'm doing it manually, selecting the 8th eq of .text img to insert before the 8th eq of .text p:first-child.

So in a photo/photoset post I could point to the captions and make them appear after the images, but in a text post everything is wrapped in the {body}, thus needing to select the particular post's image eq(8) to be matched and called up before that particular post's text eq(8)

```
$(".text img").eq(8).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(8));
$(".text img").eq(7).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(7));
$(".text img").eq(6).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(6)); 
$(".text img").eq(5).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(5)); 
$(".text img").eq(4).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(4)); 
$(".text img").eq(3).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(3));
$(".text img").eq(2).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(2));
$(".text img").eq(1).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(1));
$(".text img").eq(0).insertBefore($('.text p:first-child').eq(0));
```

The reason for using a text post to post images was to workaround the 10 imgs restriction on tumblr photoset posts.

Is there a way that I can code it such that every time a new text post is posted it will select that and insertbefore accordingly? The insertbefore is so that in my index-page, the first-child image and the first-child text would appear.

I know perhaps selecting eq is not the way to go...

(I've placed the relevant portion of the html and css code here, if I'm still lacking anything please let me know!!)
My Html code:

```
<div class="grid">
<div class ="autopagerize_page_element">
<div id="list">
        {block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="1280"} 


            {block:Text}

                {block:IndexPage}
                <div class="grid-sizer grid-item">
                    <div class="text">
                    <a href="{Permalink}">
                    {body}
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/block:IndexPage}

            {block:PermalinkPage}
                <div class="postperm">
                    <div class="perm-right text1">
                    {body}
                    </div>
                    <div class="perm-left text2">
                        <div class="captionPerm">{body}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/block:PermalinkPage}

            {/block:Text}


         {block:Photo}
            {block:IndexPage}
                <div class="grid-sizer grid-item photo">
                <a class="photos" href="{Permalink}">
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                </a>
                {block:Caption}
                    <div class="spacePhotos"></div>
                    <div class="caption">

                    {Caption}</div>
                {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:IndexPage}

        {block:PermalinkPage}
            <div class="postperm">
                <div class="perm-right">
                    <img alt="{PhotoAlt}" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">
                </div>
                <div class="perm-left">
                 {block:Caption}
                    <div class="captionPerm">{Caption}</div>
                 {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/block:PermalinkPage}
        {/block:Photo}
<!------------- PANORAMA* NOT CONFIGURED -------------------> 
            {block:Panorama}
                <div class="post panorama">
                    {LinkOpenTag}
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                    {LinkCloseTag}
                    {block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:Panorama}


        {block:Photoset}
            {block:IndexPage}
                <div class="grid-sizer grid-item photoset">
                    <a class="photos" href="{Permalink}">
                        {block:Photos}
                        <img alt="" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">
                        {/block:Photos}
                    </a>
                    {block:Caption}
                    <div class="spacePhotos"></div>
                    <div class="caption">

                        {Caption}
                    </div>
                     {/block:Caption}

                </div>
            {/block:IndexPage}

            {block:PermalinkPage}
                <div class="postperm">
                    <div class="perm-right">
                        {block:Photos}
                        <img alt="" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">
                        {/block:Photos}
                    </div>
                    <div class="perm-left">
                       {block:Caption}
                       <div class="captionPerm">{Caption}</div>
                       {/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/block:PermalinkPage}
        {/block:Photoset}

<!----------------- THE REST! *NOT CONFIGURED ------------------>        
            {block:Quote}
                <div class="post quote">
                    "{Quote}"

                    {block:Source}
                        <div class="source">{Source}</div>
                    {/block:Source}
                </div>
            {/block:Quote}{block:Link}
                <div class="post link">
                    <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>

                    {block:Description}
                        <div class="description">{Description}</div>
                    {/block:Description}
                </div>
            {/block:Link}{block:Chat}
                <div class="post chat">
                    {block:Title}
                        <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    {/block:Title}

                    <ul class="chat">
                        {block:Lines}
                            <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                {block:Label}
                                    <span class="label">{Label}</span>
                                {/block:Label}{Line}
                            </li>
                        {/block:Lines}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {/block:Chat}


            {block:Video}
                <div class="post video">
                    {Video-500}{block:Caption}
                         <div class="spacePhotos"></div>
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:Video}{block:Audio}
                <div class="post audio">
                    {AudioEmbed}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:Audio}


             {/block:Posts}
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.index-page .grid-item .caption p,
    .index-page .grid-item .text p {
        margin:auto;
    }
    .index-page .grid-item .caption p {
        display: none;
        padding-top:15px;
        line-height:125%;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .index-page .grid-item .caption p:first-child{
        display:block;
    }
    .index-page .photos img{
        display: none;
    }
    .index-page .photos img:first-child{
        display: block;
    }

    .index-page .text a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }


    .index-page .text p {
        display:none;
       padding-top:15px;
        line-height:125%;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
       max-width:90%;
    }
    .index-page .text p:first-of-type{
        display: block;
    }

    .read_more { 
        display: none; 
    }
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: use `.last()` method?

Comment: Show the HTML structure

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a little bit vague because images in text posts wouldn't make sense to be flipped around. Are you instead trying to swap around the captions of images and the images themselves?

Comment: I have added the html/css code! @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I have added the html/css code! @Satpal

Comment: @chloe784 Because Tumblr has a restriction of 10 images per post on photoset/photos, but in the text post it doesnt have that restriction. So I was trying to workaround it, I have edited my post and I hope it's more understandable now!